# sign document with certificate installed in windows C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature, x509certificate2

I took some test certificates that the password is 1234 , but when I try to sign it returns a private key error with error , but even so I didn't want it to be like that , my desire is to get the windows certificates that the user selects which one he wants by typing , then he would select the document he wants to sign, but when I try to sign that document with the certificate it gives a private key error, what could it be, is there any function that already does that?

I want to sign a document just by selecting the certificate

essa função recebe o certificado obtido do windowns ja instalado no computador , a senha do certificado no caso para instalar ele ("1234") o caminho do pdf e o caminho para salvar porem sempre me retorna um erro

```c#
static void SignDocument(X509Certificate2 certificado, string senhaCertificado, string caminhoArquivoPdf, string caminhoSalvar)
{
    try
    {
        // Carregar o arquivo PDF a ser assinado
        byte[] conteudoArquivo = File.ReadAllBytes(caminhoArquivoPdf);

        // Criar o leitor de PDF
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(conteudoArquivo);

        // Criar o arquivo de saída assinado
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(caminhoSalvar, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            // Criar o escritor de PDF
            PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, fs, '\0', null, true);

            // Criar a aparência da assinatura
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
            appearance.Reason = "Motivo da assinatura";
            appearance.Location = "Local da assinatura";
            appearance.CertificationLevel = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED;

            // Converter o certificado para o formato PKCS#12 (PFX)
            byte[] certificadoBytes = certificado.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12);
            Pkcs12Store store = new Pkcs12StoreBuilder().Build();
            store.Load(new MemoryStream(certificadoBytes), senhaCertificado.ToCharArray());
            string alias = store.Aliases.Cast<string>().FirstOrDefault();
            AsymmetricKeyEntry keyEntry = store.GetKey(alias);
            X509CertificateEntry[] certEntries = store.GetCertificateChain(alias);
            X509CertificateEntry certEntry = certEntries[0];

            // Criar o objeto de assinatura digital
            ICipherParameters key = keyEntry.Key;
            Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] certChain = certEntries.Select(entry => entry.Certificate).ToArray();
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.IExternalSignature signature = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.PrivateKeySignature(key, "SHA-256");

            // Configurar a aparência da assinatura
            appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 36, 144, 72), reader.NumberOfPages, null);

            // Assinar o documento
            MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, signature, certChain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);

            stamper.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ocorreu um erro ao assinar o documento: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You appear to use iTextSharp v5. Have you considered using its [`X509Certificate2Signature`](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/security/X509Certificate2Signature.cs) instead of the `PrivateKeySignature` you currently use? `X509Certificate2Signature` may be able to directly use your `X509Certificate2 certificado`.

Comment: I've been trying for two weeks to make this function to sign but I haven't been successful I've tried several different libraries and also classes provided in the forum I don't know if and because I'm a beginner, I checked the package version and everything ok but always something goes wrong because I'm using the certificate as x509certificate2, would there be any function to sign passing the certificate as x509certificate2 and the pdf directory?

Comment: That's why I asked: *You appear to use iTextSharp v5. Have you considered using its `X509Certificate2Signature` instead of the `PrivateKeySignature` you currently use?* TThat should allow you to easily use your `X509Certificate2` for signing.

Comment: It's a really good one, I added the itext7 class manually and created the x509certificate2signature, it worked, but I always have an error with the chain because I already get the certificate as x509certificate2, and I don't know how to convert it anymore

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, could you take a look at how I'm converting the chain?

https://github.com/fariaotavio12/GetCertificate/blob/main/ConsoleAppCertifcate/ConsoleAppCertifcate/Program.cs

Comment: Can you share an example PDF signed with that code? It's easier for me to first analyze the issue in the result before trying to identify the cause itself.